# Getting the values from a repeated Embedded Schema using TOM.NET API in an event handler in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

I am working on the Event Handler for saving a component.

My objective is to perform some validations when the user creates and component based on a schema.

I have a schema with the name "Employee".

Employee has an embedded schema with the name "Experience" and it is multivalued.

Experience has 3 fields.

1. Role : Drop down with the values Manager, Lead.
2. Company: Text field
3. Years: Text field

When the user enters some data in these fields, I want to do some validations before save.

The high level design would look like this.

1. Load the instance of the Component
2. Navigate to embedded field "Experience"

For every "Experience". I need to get the value of the "Role", and check that appropriate value is entered in other two fields(By writing Component Save event)

```
For( all the repeated "Experience")
{
    If (Role=="Manager")
        check the values in the other two fields and do some validation
    If (Role=="Lead") 
        check the values in the other two fields and do some validation
}
```

I am stuck at extracting the value and Names of subfields at the embeddded field.

I have tried:

```
Tridion.ContentManager.Session mySession = sourcecomp.Session;
Schema schema= sourcecomp.Schema;
if(schema.Title.Equals("Employee"))
{
    var compFields = new ItemFields(sourcecomp.Content, sourcecomp.Schema);
    var embeddefield = (EmbeddedSchemaField)compFields["Experience"];

    var embeddedfields = (IList<EmbeddedSchemaField>)embeddefield.Values;
    foreach(var a in embeddedfields)
    {
        if(a.Name.Equals("Role"))
        {
            string value=a.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Actually I am stuck how to retrieve the values in the other fields at the same time.

Can any one explain how it can be done?

Comment: Can you specify what version of SDL Tridion you are using?

Comment: i am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to understand on a EmbeddedSchemaField class is that it represents *both* a schema and a field (as the name implies...)

I always find it helpful to look at the source XML of the component when writing code that targets its fields, you get a good visual representation of what your classes must do. If you look at a component XML like this:

```xml
<Content>
    <Title>Some Title</Title>
    <Body>
            <ParagraphTitle>Title 1</ParagraphTitle>        
            <ParagraphContent>Some Content</ParagraphContent>
    </Body>
    <Body>
            <ParagraphTitle>Title 2</ParagraphTitle>        
            <ParagraphContent>Some more Content</ParagraphContent>
    </Body>
</Content>
```

Body is your embedded Schema field, which is multivalued, and contains 2 single-valued fields within it.

Addressing these fields in TOM.NET then:

```cs
// The Component
Component c = (Component)engine.GetObject(package.GetByName(Package.ComponentName));
// The collection of fields in this component
ItemFields content = new ItemFields(c.Content, c.Schema);
// The Title field:
TextField contentTitle = (TextField)content["Title"];
// contentTitle.Value = "Some Title"
// Get the Embedded Schema Field "Body"
EmbeddedSchemaField body = (EmbeddedSchemaField)content["Body"];
// body.Value is NOT a field, it's a collection of fields.
// Since this happens to be a multi-valued field, we'll use body.Values
foreach(ItemFields bodyFields in body.Values)
{
    SingleLineTextField bodyParagraphTitle = (SingleLineTextField)bodyFields["ParagraphTitle"];
    XhtmlField bodyParagraphContent = (XhtmlField) bodyFields["ParagraphContent"];
}
```

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that sourcecomp.Content contains the XML of the component XML, so you can simply parse the information you need from the XML.